# Scrolling to a specific row when using row height estimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with variable height rows. When I implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` and subsequently attempt to scroll programmatically to a specific row (the bottom-most row is a good test case), it seems that the estimated heights are used to calculate the necessary offset. This can lead to inaccurate scroll positions.

Is this behavior documented anywhere, and how might I scroll accurately whilst keeping the performance gains of estimation?

Comment: I've got a similar problem when a table with estimated heights is reloaded when the table is not scrolled to the top. It jumps up because my estimations are less than the real heights for the non-visible cells above the visible area that just had their height invalidated. The only solution I've found so far is to turn off estimated heights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a certain amount of cells that really needs that performance that estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath gives you should scroll coarse first then rescroll when the cell finally loads. I can't imagine much circumstances where the precalc height isn't the end height but it should always be close.

You could also roll your own thing without precalculated cells (escape UITableView entirely perhaps) and get a straight answer directly.